# Unable to initialize slf4j

Tags: logging, slf4j, executable-jar

I have created an executable jar file where I am relying on slf4j for logging. However I am getting the following warnings

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have my logger setting in the properties file along with all the other properties.

Here is a snippet that deals with initing logger

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
```

I launch my jar and place properties onto the classpath along with all the other libraries.

```
java -cp .;Mailer.jar;Mailer_lib/* com.dtn.health.mail.Mailer
```

I know that classpath is read because database calls are made properly. Application completes major tasks without issues.

In the lib folder I have 3 jars that deal with logging. They are log4j-1.2.17.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar .

I have no idea why logger is not initialized with the properties that I am setting. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig) in the warning:

> This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration.

Do you have a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` in your classpath?  (And if you do, is there any appender configured?)